# In MIPS TLB, Confusion between virtual and physical addresses

Tags: c, mips, cpu, tlb, soc

I have some C code running in RTL mode, I use `CPU I6400` the C code is just a simple code to read and write from some subsystem, for example,

I tried to write in this address :  `0x001e400000` (physical address) so when CPU executes this address I got a `TLB exception` because this address is a mapped area, after many research I fond that I need to translate this address from Virtual address to physical address, I replace this address by `0xffffffffbe400000 (Kseg1)`, now im able to write some value in this address is done, But when I tried to read from this address(W/R) or another address I got an exception on KSEG2,

Have you an idea why the writing step pass correctly but the reading step generate a exception?

Comment: What does your question have to do with RTL or SystemVerilog?

Comment: i worked on the verification of a SOC Design  who use MIPS as CPU and this design DUT is instantiated in TESTBENCH (System verilog), but my question is for who master the CPU MIPS Architecture